# What is GO_TAGS in Docker - Hyperledger/fabric-ca?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I tried to build the docker image of Hyperledger/fabric-ca from binaries. I had an issue and I looked up on the web an answer. I found an advice : use the GO_TAGS parameters when doing the "make". I wonder what is this parameter for? Is it specific to Fabric-CA?

I am looking for general information on this particular parameter. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling certain features (e.g. pkcs11) in the peer and orderer binaries requires Go build tags. This change passes GO_TAGS to the peer and orderer Docker targets.

To learn more, visit the official documentation [here.](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking for documentation about it to understand the general concept behind, and I was simply missing the name to look for: "build tags". For those interested, here is the link for go: https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/